# Shell: How to uninstall all related packages to a specific one? / Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, uninstall

Recently I asked to my hosting provider to reload the OS to `Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit minimal` assuming minimal would have the minimum required packages installed, but I realized that mysql was installed so, as I don't need it, I want to uninstall all packages related to it.

What I did was:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
```

However I'm still finding mysql binaries and files

```
$ whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/bin/X11/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

I'm thinking something like

```
$ dpkg -s mysql*
```

But this didn't help.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `apt-get remove` for a file contained in a specific package you can do:

```
apt-get remove $(dpkg  -S /usr/bin/mysql | cut -d ':' -f 1)
```

(replace `/usr/bin/mysql`, with whatever file you were looking for to remove)

Using this, `apt-get` will still ask if you really want to remove the package (that dpkg found), sometimes you realise you did not want that after you see the package name

Answer (score 5):

Why are you so sure you don't need it? Perhaps other packages depend on it, it is not used exclusively to set up a mysql server, some programs manage their internal DBs using it for example.

Now, to answer your question, the first step is indeed to find out what package installed those files:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/mysql
mysql-client-core-5.5: /usr/bin/mysql
```

That's the output from an Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Machine, yours will probably be a different version but the same principle applies.Now you know the package name and can remove it manually.

Basically, the two packages you removed are both [meta packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that point to other packages. So, when you removed them, you only removed the dummy package and not everything that was installed with them. To remove everything related to mysql, run this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-*
```